# How to permanently disable autosuspend for specific USB port?

Tags: usb, suspend

I want to disable autosuspend for a single USB port. I have tested the following successfully:

```
sudo echo on > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2.4/power/control
```

How can I make this configuration permanent? Few sources mention `/etc/rc.local`, but I am not sure if this is the correct place. The USB port I am targeting is part of a docking station, so it may not be present. Sure I can check if that USB device is present, but I am suspecting that there is a better solution. It is also possible to disable autosuspend for all ports using `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`. Is there a draw-back to disabling autosuspend for all devices? The only USB device that I have plugged in at all times (asides from keyboard and mouse) is a webcam. Will there be noticeably more power consumption if autosuspend is disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to set up sth permanently is to create a systemd service.
In your case I'd write sth like this:
`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/usbsuspend.service`(choose anyName.service)
It's content:

```
[Unit]
Description= Your description here

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart= echo>on > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2.4/power/control

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To enable that service execute:

`sudo systemctl enable usbsuspend.service`(or your service name)

To start the service right away:

`sudo systemctl start usbsuspend.service`

Comment: I like that solution, but I had to run the command like this: `/bin/sh -c 'echo on > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2.4/power/control'` to solve `Executable path is not absolute: echo>on > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2.4/power/control`

Comment: Yes, it depends. Basically I wanted to point you into the direction of services.  An alternative would have been to put that command in a bash file and call that executable with `ExecStart`