# How do I run an .sh file on boot?

Tags: 20.04, scripts, java, raspberrypi

I'm using Ubuntu Server 20.04 for Raspberry Pi 4, I'm trying to get a .sh file to run at boot, so I can just plug the Pi in and it runs the script, but how do I do that.

Answer (score 2):

`systemctl` is what you're looking for. You'll need to install the script somewhere appropriate. Then, create a service file. Make sure that the file is executable (`chmod +x /your/file.sh`).

More details can be found here:
[How do I run a single command at startup using systemd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd)

Comment: Look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1264589/906933) for a more elaborate answer

Comment: If that link makes you think you need "spark" it's just an example. Here's a [generic link] (https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-run-script-on-startup-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-server-desktop)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via cron. Create a file (with any name you choose) in directory `/etc/cron.d` which contains the following:

```
@reboot root /path/to/your/file.sh
```

(the .sh file needs to be executable of course)

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you edit `$ sudo nano /boot/config.txt`  and add what you need to start on boot, here is another way in more detailed explanation, copy and paste to new browser tab.

https://raspberrytips.com/autostart-a-program-on-boot/